# dart how to return a future

Tags: function, dart, future

In dart, I want to write a function that returns a future. 
I cannot find an example anywhere and have not figured it out myself yet.

The function contains calls to other functions that return futures and also sequential code.

E.g.: 
I have some class:

```
class Basic {
 int x;
}
```

imagine there already exists a function:

```
Future<int> f(int x);
```

My function should return a Basic object with the value of f() + some number:

```
Future<Basic> myFunction(int y) {

 Basic b;

 f(y).then((z) {
  b.x = z + y;
  return b;
 });
}
```

When I call this in main:

```
void main() {
 Future<Basic> basic_future = myFunction(3);

 basic_future.then((result) => print(result.x));

}
```

the basic_future.then statement throws an exception because basic_future is null, i.e. I think what happens is that myFunction come outs before f() is run and returns null hence basic_future is null. Later f() returns and the proper basic_future is returned, but too late.

How to solve this?
(hope this was understandable)

Thanks,
imran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Future.then](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_async/Future.html#then) returns a `Future`. So you only have to return the result of your `then` call :

```dart
Future<Basic> myFunction(int y) {
  return f(y).then((z) {
    Basic b = new Basic();
    b.x = z + y;
    return b;
  });
}
```